# Sentencia like con parametros

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedure, buscador

Tengo el siguiente procedimiento:

```
create procedure buscar(
in producto) 

begin 
select nombre from producto where nombre like'%'+producto+'%' 
end
```

pero me da error en el like

intente usando

```
create procedure buscar(
    in producto) 
    begin 
    select nombre from producto where nombre like'%'||producto||'%' 
    end
```

pero al momento de realizar una busqueda no me aparecen los productos similares

por ejemplo hago

```
call Buscador_Producto('c');
```

y no me aparecen los productos que empiezan con c, tengo que escribir el nombre completo del producto

Comment: ¿Has probado con [`nombre LIKE CONCAT('%', producto, '%')`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)?

Comment: Por cierto, ¿qué servidor de bases de datos usas? Esa sintaxis no es de SQL Server. ¿Podrías especificar cuál es para darte el código exacto?

Comment: Me ha funcionado perfectamente, estoy usando mysql, lo hice tal como dijiste y funciono, lo siguiente que hice fue hacerlo de esta forma 
nombre LIKE CONCAT(producto, '%')

para que solo buscara la letra inicial, mil gracias

Comment: Había hecho la prueba con MS SQL Server aquí: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0a630/1/0 te redacto la respuesta ya que el operador `||` es de Oracle, no funciona ni en MySQL ni en MS SQL Server ni en otros servidores.

Comment: @OscarGarcia sí funciona en PostgreSQL, no es exclusivo de Oracle. Voy a añadir la etiqueta `mysql` a la pregunta. Recomiendo al OP marcar la respuesta como correcta

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema que sufres es que el operador de concatenación de cadenas `||` funciona en motores como [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/operators003.htm) y [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html), pero no funciona en MySQL ni es estándar en otros servidores de bases de datos.

Puedes solucionarlo usando el operador de concatenación de cadenas [`CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) de la siguiente manera:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE buscar(IN producto)
BEGIN
    SELECT
      nombre
    FROM producto
    WHERE
      nombre LIKE CONCAT('%', producto, '%')
END
```

Comment: edité un poco la respuesta para añadir PG en las excepciones donde || sí funciona

Comment: Gracias por la edición, la iba a hacer yo cuando me salió el mensaje de respuesta editada :)

Comment: Para mí es un honor tener la oportunidad de mejorar una respuesta tuya, Oscar, estoy consciente de que sabes más que yo :blush:

Comment: Gracias por el elogio @amenadiel , pero creo que saber mucho de algo en concreto no me convierte en gurú de todo. Todo es relativo ;) Yo también aprendo mucho día a día solucionando preguntas planteadas o leyendo las respuestas de otros compañeros.

Comment: Bueno, todos estamos aquí para aprender lo que no sabemos y perfeccionar lo que ya sabemos. Hay muchas cosas que hago a diario que no me molesté en entender *por qué* funcionaban así hasta que tuve que explicarlo en este sitio.